# Are there simple tests of UV protection claims

Tags: radiation

Many consumer products claim to protect users against UV rays. Is there a test an educated consumer can do to verify the claim?

Typical objects sold with such claims are sunglasses, articles of clothing, umbrellas, and creams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can purchase a thing called a UV dosimetry tag, which is a stick-on square of yellowish paper that changes color to dark green as it accumulates UV dosage. these come in die-cut sheets and each sheet has lots of tags on it and costs a few dollars per sheet.

In your case, you would calibrate a set of tags by placing them out in the sun for  1, 2, 3, 4, ... minutes each and noting the color change that results. Then for example you would place a sheet of protective fabric over the tag, set it out in the sun for a fixed time, and compare the color change in the tag to your set of standards.  If the tag protected by fabric for 2 minutes in the sun experiences the same color change as an unprotected tag exposed for one minute, then the fabric cut the UV dose by one half.

Google "UV dosimetry tag" to find the firm that sells these on-line.